# using semantic package to return documents

Tags: java, methods

I'm pretty new to Java,, I found this example and trying to run it,,, should I just pass the name of the function with its parameter? Specifically, I'm trying to run document search by terms using the package https://github.com/semanticvectors/semanticvectors/wiki

```
public boolean runSearch(String query, List<String> keywords, List<String> answers) throws IOException, ZeroVectorException {

        String docsVec = DOC_VECTOR_Q;
        String termsVec = TERM_VECTOR_QA;
        String luceneIndex = QUESTIONS_ANSWERS_INDEX;

        String[] args = { "-docvectorsfile", docsVec, "-termvectorsfile", termsVec, "-luceneindexpath", luceneIndex };

        LuceneUtils luceneUtils = null;


        String s = query.toLowerCase();

        String[] queryArray = s.split(" ");

        FlagConfig config = FlagConfig.getFlagConfig(args);
        CloseableVectorStore queryVecReader = VectorStoreReader.openVectorStore(config.termvectorsfile(), config);
        CloseableVectorStore resultsVecReader = VectorStoreReader.openVectorStore(config.docvectorsfile(), config);
        luceneUtils = new LuceneUtils(config);
        VectorSearcher vecSearcher = new VectorSearcher.VectorSearcherCosine(queryVecReader, resultsVecReader,
                luceneUtils, config, queryArray);
        LinkedList<SearchResult> results = vecSearcher.getNearestNeighbors(10);

        queryVecReader.close();
        resultsVecReader.close();

        return isAutoResponse;
```

I already implemented the following, and it's working fine, but returns terms instead of the actual documents:

```
public class ExampleVectorSearcherClient {

  public static String DEFAULT_VECTOR_FILE = "src/test/resources/termvectors.bin";

  /**
   * Opens vector store from given arg, or if this is empty uses {@link #DEFAULT_VECTOR_FILE}.
   * Then prompts the user for terms to search for.
   *
   * @throws IOException If vector store can't be found.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String vectorStoreName;
    if (args.length == 0) {
      vectorStoreName = DEFAULT_VECTOR_FILE;
    } else {
      vectorStoreName = args[0];
    }

    FlagConfig defaultFlagConfig = FlagConfig.getFlagConfig(null);
    VectorStoreRAM searchVectorStore = VectorStoreRAM.readFromFile(defaultFlagConfig, vectorStoreName);
    LuceneUtils luceneUtils = null;  // Not needed for this simple demo.

    while(true) {
      System.out.println("Enter a query term:");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String queryString = sc.nextLine();
      try {
        VectorSearcher searcher = new VectorSearcher.VectorSearcherCosine(
            searchVectorStore, searchVectorStore, luceneUtils, defaultFlagConfig, queryString.split("\\s+"));
        LinkedList<SearchResult> results = searcher.getNearestNeighbors(10);
        for (SearchResult result : results) {
          System.out.println(result.getScore() + ":" + result.getObjectVector().getObject());
        }
      } catch (ZeroVectorException e) {
        System.out.println("No vector for strings: '" + queryString + "'.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And to do for documents, it's explained here https://github.com/semanticvectors/semanticvectors/wiki/DocumentSearch, and tried to integrate as the following but it's complaining about compilation problems:

```
   public class ExampleVectorSearcherClient {


      public static String Index_FILE = "C:\\Users\\positional_index";
      public static String DEFAULT_VECTOR_FILE = "C:\\Users\\termvectors.bin";
      public static String DEFAULT_DOC_FILE = "C:\\Users\\docvectors.bin";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          String vectorStoreName;

          if (args.length == 0) {
              vectorStoreName = DEFAULT_VECTOR_FILE;
             } else {
              vectorStoreName = args[0];
             }

          FlagConfig defaultFlagConfig = FlagConfig.getFlagConfig(null);
          VectorStoreRAM queryVecReader = VectorStoreRAM.readFromFile(defaultFlagConfig, vectorStoreName);
          VectorStoreRAM resultsVecReader = VectorStoreRAM.readFromFile(defaultFlagConfig, DEFAULT_DOC_FILE);


          LuceneUtils luceneUtils = null;
          VectorSearcher  vecSearcher = new VectorSearcher.VectorSearcherCosine( 
                  queryVecReader, resultsVecReader, luceneUtils, defaultFlagConfig, new String[] {"heart", "failure"}); 
          LinkedList<SearchResult> results = vecSearcher.getNearestNeighbors(10);

          for (SearchResult result: results) {
              System.out.println(String.format(
               "%f:%s",
              result.getScore(),
              result.getObjectVector().getObject().toString()));


    }
      }}
```